# Write an array via loop

Tags: php

I need to write an array that looks like this:

```
$years = array('12', '11', '10', '09', '08');
```

I would like to have a script that will create this array, so that I don't have to update it every year.

Tried this:

```
for ($i = date("y"); $i >= 08; $i++) {
    $yrs .= '"'.$i.'", ';
}

$years = array($yrs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to decrement in your loop instead of increment, since you are trying to go from 12 down to 8. So change your ++ to --. You can also append to an array using the `$years[] = ...` notation, and make an array using `$years = array()`:

```
$years = array();
for ($i = date("y"); $i >= 8; $i--)
    $years[] = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

`print_r($years)` gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 09
    [4] => 08
)
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VDQNj2

Comment: It looks great but I get an array all the way to year 2000. Can I stop it at 2008 (08)?

Comment: Just a note, in your example the loop _should_ stop at `08`, but doesn't because you prefixed the number 8 with a zero, causing it to be interpreted as an octal number. However, since 8 is an invalid digit for an octal number, it gets converted to the [integer value 0](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BgyRLj). To fix it, just remove the 0! `:)`

Comment: Yes sorry, I had it right in my answer, but wrong in that codepad link for some reason. Here is a new codepad: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BOktOr Thanks @nickb

Comment: @user1131166 See my reply to nickb :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$years = array();

for ($i = date("y"); $i >= 8; $i--) {
    $years[] = substr("00".$i,-2);
}
```

Comment: @user1 I just stole the $i-- from you - just mentioning it so pls accept user1's answer

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [range](http://php.net/range) function helps out a lot here:

## 4-digit years

```
$thisYear = date('Y'); // "2012"
$years = range($thisYear, $thisYear-4);

// array(2012,2011,2010,2009,2008)
```

## 2-digit years

```
$thisYear = date('y'); // "2012"
$years = range($thisYear, $thisYear-4);

// array(12,11,10,9,8)
```

### + adding zero-padding to 2-digit years

```
$years = array_map(function($year) {
    return sprintf('%02u', $year);
}, $years);

// array("12","11","10","09","08")
```

Note: The use of an inline function (closure) for array_map requires PHP 5.3+